# How to remove Left and bottom Border in react chart js 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

[image: How to remove left and bottom border as i mention in picture.]

How to remove left and bottom border as i mention in picture.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to do it using only the `options` attribute of `react-chartjs-2` or `Chart.js`. But you can customize your own chart using the `plugins` attribute inside `options`.

See the docs for more : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html

Comment: can you give a example ?